# How do I limit height of some divs to other divs in the same parent div with display flex row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div with `display:flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;`
Inside it there are child divs, lets call them a b c d

Each div has `<ul></ul>` with multiple items inside it.
So it's something like this:

```html
<style>
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .list-container {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .list-container h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .list-container ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
</style>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="list-container">
    <h2>List A</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container">
    <h2>List B</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container">
    <h2>List C</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
      <li>Item 16</li>
      <li>Item 17</li>
      <li>Item 18</li>
      <li>Item 19</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container">
    <h2>List D</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Divs b and c can take very huge amount of items, so I want to limit their height.

How do I limit b and c height to max height of all other divs, if they are bigger, making them scrollable in this case? **I need a solution without a and d height fixed** in css(something like `height: 100px;`) as some internet solutions suggest because they are dynamic and can change their height too

Comment: Where do you want the cutoff to be exactly? How many items should be there before it becomes scrollable? And are you saying the height of A and D should be `fit-content` instead of all columns having the same height?

Comment: @MissSkooter I need a and d divs to take all the height they need for their content, but for b and c only take height of max(height a; height d)

Comment: Okay, but what if A had 20 items? then taking the max(height A; height D) would stop making sense no? since you'd end up with really long unnecessary columns. Or is that the intended behavior?

Comment: @MissSkooter Yes it is, height of divs that aren't b or c is never big(there is actually more than two of such divs in my casse, I just simplified it), only b and c can ever get much bigger than other divs

Comment: @tacoshy it does not because it is using fixed height in pixels which is not the solution that I need as I already mentioned in my question

Comment: @maxpovver then you haven't read the answers... there is no fixed height there

Comment: @tacoshy min-height: 100px; is still fixing height to some number in pixels which is not what I need

Comment: which is an example to simualte it not a necessity

Comment: @tacoshy this absolute position hack is not even workig for more than one div, try it yourself, they are all just put on each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we're allowed to add an extra div inside the height-limited divs, we can do something like this:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list-container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list-container h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.list-container ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.flexible {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flexible .flexible-child {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="list-container">
    <h2>List A</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container flexible">
    <div class="flexible-child">
      <h2>List B</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
        <li>Item 10</li>
        <li>Item 11</li>
        <li>Item 12</li>
        <li>Item 13</li>
        <li>Item 14</li>
        <li>Item 15</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container flexible">
    <div class="flexible-child">
      <h2>List C</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
        <li>Item 10</li>
        <li>Item 11</li>
        <li>Item 12</li>
        <li>Item 13</li>
        <li>Item 14</li>
        <li>Item 15</li>
        <li>Item 16</li>
        <li>Item 17</li>
        <li>Item 18</li>
        <li>Item 19</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container">
    <h2>List D</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: misses simplicity compared to the already existing duplicates.

Comment: @tacoshy doesn't the existing duplicates involve fixed height?

Comment: thank you @Damzaky, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: no it uses `position: absolute`+  `top/bottom: 0`. which is 3 liner

Comment: @tacoshy hmm ok, imho though, using `absolute` positioning in this case is more of a hacky way and less flex-y way, but whatever, just trying to help

Comment: @Damzaky absolute solution is also not working for two divs nearby, they are just put in exactly the same position. Your solution is much better, thanks

Comment: strange, then you must have done something wrong. I use it on daily basis...